# FInd minimum and maximum number of tuples in R U πA,B ( R⋈S )

Tags: database-design, join, union, dbms, relational-algebra

Given two relations **R(A,B)**  with r tuples, **S(B,C)** with s tuples (r>0, s>0), find the min and max number of tuples in this relation:

**R U π<sub>A,B</sub> ( R⋈S )**

Given options are:

- -min:r, max:r+s
- -min:0, max:r
- -min:min(r,s), max:max(r,s)
- -min:r, max:r

Now I know the individual max and min of both union(min=max(r,s) and max=r+s) and join(min=0 max=s) and I know that **min and max of π<sub>A,B</sub> ( R⋈S ) are 0 and r*s** but I can't find my way in this combined relation.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general a Union doesn't 'filter out' any tuples, then the cardinality of the result is at least the cardinality of the higher-cardinality operand.

The Projection is on to the original heading of `R`, so it can't produce any more tuples than were in `R`, neither can it produce tuples that weren't already in `R`.

Then the answer is -min:r, max:r .